# generate D3 html pages with R?

Tags: r, d3.js

I would like to generate an interactive plot with R, for example an xyplot that shows information of the data points on mouseover, and I've read about D3. I would like to be able to write R code to generate the D3 html pages automatically. Is there any R package able to do that?

I've seen there is a r2d3 package on github but I am not sure how far that project is. Any ideas?

Comment: This question is vague and likely to be closed as it currently stands.  Consider asking a more specific question and trying the package yourself first.

Comment: I have now rephrased my question, hopefully it will be clearer.

Comment: I found a way of doing this with Shiny and ggvis, but using ggvis plots in my Shiny website crashes the page (greyed out) every once in a while. Still don't know why.

Answer (score 4):

Looks to be fairly early in its development: https://github.com/hadley/r2d3. Hadley generally makes announcements when things are ready to test and then puts his packages on CRAN when they are ready for prime-time. (There's also confusion in that some versions of D3 on Github are named r2d3 when they have nothing to do with R): https://www.google.com/url?q=https://github.com/mhemesath/r2d3&sa=U&ei=Ig-YULraMueimQWxhYHgCA&ved=0CAwQFjAC&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNGe9p5iKH6deoHDpd2yKHJds8Qdow